# Get property of class in hastable

Tags: c#, hashtable

i have hashtable that save string as key and class for the detail, now i need access member of class in detail. i have code like this:

```
private readonly Hashtable _data = new Hashtable();
public ResultStatus Register<T,T1,T2>( T dataT, T1 dataT1,T2 dataT2 ) 
{      
  if( _data.ContainsKey( dataT ) )
  {
    return ResultStatus.DuplicateData;
  }
  var dataItem = new DataItem<T,T1,T2>( dataT,dataT1,dataT2 );
  if( !_validatorManager.IsValid( (int)(object)dataT2 ) )
  {
    return ResultStatus.ContentError;
  }
  _data.Add( dataT, dataItem );
  return ResultStatus.Success;
}
```

and my DataItem Class :

```
public class DataItem<T,T1,T2>
  {
    public T ItemName { get; set; }
    public T1 ItemContent { get; set; }
    public T2 ItemType { get; set; }

    public DataItem( T name, T1 content, T2 type )
    {
      ItemName = name;
      ItemContent = content;
      ItemType = type;      
    }
}
```

and another class to retrieve it's content :

```
public Tuple<ResultStatus, T1> GetType<T,T1>( T itemName )
{

  if( !_data.ContainsKey( itemName ) )
  {
    return new Tuple<ResultStatus, T1>( ResultStatus.Success, ( T1 ) ( object ) 0 );
  }
  else
  {
    return new Tuple<ResultStatus, T1>( ResultStatus.Success, _data[itemName].ItemType ); ==> ?? //Here .ItemType not shown
  }
}
```

how can i access ItemType on DataItem Class ??

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a `Dictionary<T, DataItem>` instead of `Hashtable`?

Comment: not just only DataItem class, so i want more dynamic, if there any class as data transfer object i can use it my code without changing code inside

Comment: I can't really comment, the design seems a little odd to me. It seems as though you just want to be able to store arbitrary objects, so why not just let the user specify the type of the object, instead of `T1` & `T2`? All that casting going on means something is probably not right.

Comment: yup, my code is wrong :D, all i want is i want register some data to collection(hashtable,dictionary, etc) with DataItem class as data transfer object, but i want my dataitem class dynamic, so not accept only integer or some string, that why i use generic in my dto class

Comment: Looks something wrong with your design ... Maybe you can omit using `ItemType` property and use `GetType()` in your code instead ?

Comment: `(int)(object)dataT2` Doesn't that just mean `T2` should always be an `int`? Then why is it even generic?